# how to call recursively a function that has an array of structs as parameter

Tags: c++, arrays, recursion, struct, quicksort

I want to sort an array of structs by a specific member using quicksort.
here is my struct:

```
    struct points
{
    int x,y,apart;
};
```

and the quicksort function:

```
 void quicksort(points* a,int points::*member,int left, int right)

{
       int i=left, j=right, pivot=a[(i+j)/2].*member;
       while(i<j)
         {
             while(a[i].*member<pivot)
             i++;
             while(a[j].*member>pivot)
             j--;
                if(i<=j)
                  {
                      points tmp=a[i];
                      a[i]=a[j];
                      a[j]=tmp;
                      i++;j--;
                  }
         }
       if(left<j)
       quicksort(a,&points::*member,left,j);
       if(i<right)
        quicksort(a,&points::*member,i,right);
}
```

and the problem is in these two lines of code:

```
if(left<j)
       quicksort(a,&points::*member,left,j);
       if(i<right)
        quicksort(a,&points::*member,i,right);
```

It give's me the error:  expected unqualified-id before '*' token|

I don't know when I call it recursively how to specify the member I want to sort it by...
If it makes any sense please help me.
Thanks

Answer (score 2):

Easier than you think, like this

```
if(left<j)
   quicksort(a,member,left,j);
if(i<right)
   quicksort(a,member,i,right)
```

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want to do something like: "sort by x", "sort by y" as an input to the function?

In that case you can't use a pointer as that always points to a specific instance variable.

The better way in this case might be to use pass a function like `int get_sort_param(const struct points & p)` and call this in your sort algorithm whenever you are the sorted value.

Comment: He's not using a pointer, its a member pointer. Different things entirely.